# c# sockets missing data

Tags: c#, sockets

I have the following code to read messages sent from a server to the client:

```
while (true) {
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[327680];
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(327680);
    while (true) {
        do {
            int bytes = ServerStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
            message.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, bytes));
        }
        while (ServerStream.DataAvailable);

        if (message.Length > 0) {
            foreach (string msg in message.ToString().Split(MESSAGE_END)) {
                if (msg != "") ProcessServerMessage(msg);
            }
            message.Clear();
            readBuffer = new byte[327680];
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately... Every now and then the variable 'message' appears to chop off, for no reason I can understand. I've made the read buffer huge, to see if that was the issue, but it doesn't help. It seems to happen when the server sends lots of data at once, but nowhere near 327680 bytes...

Also, when checking the server logs, it appears to be sending the data completely, un-chopped. It's like half the info is 'lost' on the internet somewhere... But this is TCP, so that shouldn't happen, right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason you can't use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324)? There are a lot of things that are going on under the covers that might make the `.DataAvailable` property false even though your server side code is in the middle of a message. WCF will simplify all this for you and much more.

Comment: It's too late to change the game now, unfortunately... I didn't know about WCF. :< Is there any alternative to using .DataAvailable?

Comment: It might be worth your while. Its easy to use, lots of examples and it will probably save you loads of headaches down the road. Just a suggestion though. Otherwise go with what Chris suggests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not lost, you're not doing buffered reading correctly. Even though you're checking `DataAvailable`, odds are that the sender hasn't flushed that data yet. So it's "on the way" (waiting to be sent), but `DataAvailable` will return false because it hasn't yet arrived.

It's always better to send an integer ahead of the data so that the receiver knows how much data to expect, OR to look for some kind of terminator (null, newline, something).

Comment: Don't forget to add some sort of timeout mechanic as well so the thread doesn't get locked if the server does fail to send the end of the message.